# import export styled component reactjs

Tags: javascript, css, reactjs, styles

i want to split page between styling and app

example

in page style.js

```
import styled from "styled-components";

//i dont know how to export all const
export const Container = styled.div`
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: row;
`;

export const Sidebar = styled.div`
  width: 20%;
  height: 100%;
  background-color: #f9f9f9;
`;
```

and in page app.js

```
import * as All from "./style.js"
//i dont know, how to import all const in style.js


function App(){
return(
<Container>
<Sidebar>
</Sidebar>
</Container>
)}
```

how to export and import all const when const in style.js there are so many?

Comment: What you've done in page-style.js is fine, now just `import {Container, Sidebar} from "page-style.js"`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

another option you can export like this :

```
import styled from "styled-components";

const Container = styled.div`
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: row;
`;

const Sidebar = styled.div`
  width: 20%;
  height: 100%;
  background-color: #f9f9f9;
`;


export {Container,Sidebar}
```

and you can import like this :

```
import { Container,Sidebar } from './style';


function App() {
 return (
  <Container>
   <Sidebar>
   </Sidebar>
  </Container>
 );
}
```

Answer (score 0):

There is a beautiful way to do that. This way also let you know which component is styled-component or single component.

```
// style.js
export const Styled = {
    Container: styled.div`
        display: flex;
        flex-direction: row;
    `,
   
    Sidebar: styled.div`
        width: 20%;
        height: 100%;
        background-color: #f9f9f9;
    `,
}

import { Styled } from './style';


function App() {
 return (
  <Styled.Container>
   <Styled.Sidebar>
   </Styled.Sidebar>
  </Styled.Container>
 );
}
```

Answer (score 0):

[Dae Hyeon Mun's approach](https://stackoverflow.com/a/70828706) is great, but you can simplify it further and avoid having to refactor your `styles.js` file by using a [wildcard import](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/import#import_an_entire_modules_contents), which essentially creates a module object so you don't have to!:

```
// style.js
export const Container = styled.div`
  ...
`;

export const Sidebar = styled.div`
  ...
`;


// app.js
import * as Styled from './style';

function App() {
 return (
  <Styled.Container>
   <Styled.Sidebar>
   </Styled.Sidebar>
  </Styled.Container>
 );
}
```

More details: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Guide/Modules#creating_a_module_object

Answer (score 0):

You can use "export const" like you already did for exporting. The simplest way to import those const is:

```js
import * as styled from "./style.js"
//this will import all 'export const' containing 'styled' from "./style.js"


function App(){
return(
<Container>
<Sidebar>
</Sidebar>
</Container>
)}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/16.6.3/umd/react.production.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react-dom/16.6.3/umd/react-dom.production.min.js"></script>
```